# Android Change location accuracy

Tags: android, location, maps

I want to prompt user to change location accuracy like google maps.
The options I found were to use an Intent to navigate user to Settings to change it manually.
But google maps does it differently, it prompts you if you want to switch to high accuracy and if you click yes it changes this setting without switching to Settings app.

I wanted to know if any of you guys know any solutions to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
                googleApiClient.connect();

                LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

                //**************************
                builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
                //**************************

                PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                        final Status status = result.getStatus();
                        final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                                // requests here.
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                                // a dialog.
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                    status.startResolutionForResult(
                                            getActivity(), 1000);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    // Ignore the error.
                                }
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                                // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });             }
```